# How to remove underline from a link and add underline on hover? (images attached)

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I want underline to be removed from a link. Also I want underline to appear when I hover it with my mouse pointer. How can this be done? Pls help.

No hover:
[image: NO Hover - Normal link]

When I hover the `Login` link:
[image: When I hover the Login link]

Answer (score 11):

You need to turn off the CSS property `text-decoration` for the link and then use the `:hover` [dynamic pseudo class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) to add the `text-decoration` back when hovering.

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wzvE8/)

Also, you might also need to style the `:visited:hover` pseudo class so that the underline appears on links a user has already visited. [link order in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536810/link-order-in-css/1536822#1536822) is a good answer because the *order* of the CSS rules matters.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your login link has the id `login`...

```
#login {
   text-decoration: none;
}

#login:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your style sheet, whatever the ID is.

```
#LoginButton a:active {text-decoration: none;}
#LoginButton a:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a CSSClass within the login button and define the following lines in the style sheet,

```
   .ClassName a:link {text-decoration:none;}//removes underline


   .ClassName a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}// displays underline on mouse over
```

Hope this helps..