# How to make visited links unvisited?

Tags: html, css

Having a problem with visited links not changing into the colour they're supposed to. What's supposed to go down is, the link is black with 70% opacity. When you hover over it, it should change to aliceblue with 100% opacity. Which is only working on unvisited links. The visited links should be and are exactly the same as the normal links, besides the fact they don't change properly.

```
a{
transition: color 1s ease;
}

a:link {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 20px;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: arial;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover{
color: aliceblue;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: arial;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:visited{
transition: color 1s ease;
display: inline-block;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
margin-left: 20px;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: arial;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: I don't know weather i worded it wrong but i don't want the visited link to change colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with cascading styles in CSS, as stated here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1536822/3990818

> `a:hover` must be placed after the `a:link` and `a:visited` rules

Unless this is done, `a:visited` will override `a:hover`.

You can also experiment with this at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_link_more1 by rearranging the different CSS rules, as an easy testing ground for this problem.